# View returns null IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable, model-binding

I'm using MVC DevExpress GridView with large amount of data.

I pass list to my view, only to bind gridview to it. On submit button, I want that list to returned to controller, and saved to database. Problem is, returned list gets null when returned to controller.

Here is my model:

```
  public class PayrollModel
{

    public PayrollModel()
    {
        PayrollSearch = new PAYROLLVIEWSearch();

    }
    public PAYROLLVIEWSearch PayrollSearch { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PAYROLLVIEW> PayrollList { get; set; }
    public IList<RIGHTGROUP> RightGroupList { get; set; }
    public DateTime PayrollDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action is:

```
       [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PayrollSave(PayrollModel model)
        {
         //PayrollList is null here
        }
```

I would like to avoid using editor template, as I thing it'll slow down view rendering.

Comment: Quick check - your ViewModel is `PayrollParameterModel` whereas your action expects a `PayrollModel` ?

Comment: wrong model, I edited my question

Comment: What makes you think using an `EditorTemplate` will slow things down? How are you rendering your view?

Comment: I don't know, but it just doesn't make sense to render 1000000 elements that will be hidden, if there is another way to solve the problem

Comment: Of course not, you would need to page your data.